# Checking if element exists with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a block of code that looks like this:

```
//Account Number
        account = $(msg).find('[name=account_number]').val();

        if(account){
            $('#progressUpdates').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Found Account Number<br />');
        }else{
            $( '#progressUpdates').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Account Number not found<br />');
        }
```

The problem is, if the element that is being assigned to account doesn't exist, it throws an error. I tried doing :

```
if(account.length){}
```

But the issue isn't with the if statement, its assigning the variable. Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Current code should work. `val()` returns `undefined` is the element it is called on does not exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: have you tried typeof account !== 'undefined'?

Comment: What @techfoobar said, the posted code does not throw an error, and works just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/D3LrF/

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `val()`

`account = $(msg).find('[name=account_number]');`

and chack length -

`if(account.length){`

Comment: I need the value of that element though.

Comment: @SBB Sure... you can call `val()` if that exist,  right ?

Comment: seems like more code than needed but i guess if thats the only way

Answer (score 1):

instead of this:

```
account = $(msg).find('[name=account_number]');
```

try with removing `.val()`:

```
account = $(msg).find('[name=account_number]');
```

okay then you have to check for length in your if:

```
if(account.length){
```

or if you want the value out of it as suggested by **Anton**:

```
account.val()
```

Comment: That would tell me that it found the element but then i need the value of it as well.